# Problems passing boolean param to a pipeline child job

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have this pipeline job that needs to call a validation job like this:

```
isHardReleaseAllowed= true                
def versionOk = build(job: "/validateMVNVersion", parameters: [[$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'version', value: params.version],
                [$class: 'BooleanParameterValue', name: 'isHardReleaseAllowed', value: isHardReleaseAllowed]], propagate: true)
```

The validate job is defined as follows :

```
string(name: 'version', description: 'The new version to set')
booleanParam(name: 'isReleaseTagAllowed',defaultValue: false , description: 'is hard release tag allowed?')
```

These are my values before calling my job  (from the output console) :

echo ➡ validating version 1.12.14 tag on branch ➡release/testRelease with isHardReleaseAllowed= true

But when I echo these in my validateMVNVersion job ,

```
      echo "isReleaseTagAllowed class : \u27A1" + isReleaseTagAllowed.getClass().toString() + " value :" + isReleaseTagAllowed

      echo "env.isReleaseTagAllowed \u27A1" + env.isReleaseTagAllowed.getClass().toString() + " value :" + env.isReleaseTagAllowed
      echo "params.isReleaseTagAllowed \u27A1" + params.isReleaseTagAllowed.getClass().toString() + " value :" + params.isReleaseTagAllowed

      boolean isReleaseBranchAllowedBoolean = params.isReleaseTagAllowed == "true"
      echo "Boolean asboolean value is " + isReleaseBranchAllowedBoolean
```

I get these values :

```
isReleaseTagAllowed class : ➡class java.lang.String value :false
[Pipeline] echo
env.isReleaseTagAllowed ➡class java.lang.String value :false
[Pipeline] echo
params.isReleaseTagAllowed ➡class java.lang.Boolean value :false
[Pipeline] echo
Boolean asboolean value is false
```

All of them are false... What am I not getting?

Answer (score 0):

A good way of getting the value is by setting the right variable name ;)